# how to remove an object within an array using the object's index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

so I created an array with several objects inside it

```
const students = [
    {jean:14},
    {mike:19},
    {nean:16},
    {annie:17}
]
```

and I want to remove certain object from the array by using the object's index

```
let index = students.findIndex(i => {
    if (Object.keys(i) == 'nean'){
        return true
    }
})
```

and it returns the index of the object that I want to remove from the array and I do `.splice()` to remove it from the array. It does remove the object that I expect to be removed but it also removes the item after it

```
    students.splice(index, index)
    console.log(students) 

//(2) […] 0: Object { jean: 14 } 1: Object { mike: 19 } length: 2
```

Comment: Hi, In splice the second index should be the number of objects you want to remove from the array, so it should be always 1, but currently you are passing index. You should use `students.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: probably `array.filter()` is your friend

Comment: The logic of that `if()` doesn't really make sense. Neither does using unique keys in each object. Much simpler with structure like `[{name:'jean', age:14},{name:'mike'...}]`

Comment: what's the differences then between using unique keys in each object as i did and not

Comment: Just a lot simpler to code with consistent key names in each object

Comment: how can i use the .filter() method in order to get the same result

Answer (score 2):

When using splice, the first argument is the index and the second is how many elements to remove from that index. so in order to remove just that element, you can do: `students.splice(index, 1)`
reference: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score -1):

Array.splice() should be provided at least 2 arguments and from argument 3 to infinity are optional,

the first argument is the index where u want to start your manipulation,
the second argument is the number of items that you would like to be deleted from that index onwards,
and the third argument is the string/object that you would like to add

in your example you would like to start at the index that you have found using this function:

```js
    let index = students.findIndex(i => {
        if (Object.keys(i) == 'nean'){
            return true
        }
    })
```

and you would like to delete just one! so you need to provide 1 for the second argument and not index,

`js students.splice(index, 1)`

as you don't need to add anything you will not provide the 3rd argument,

I hope this helps with all your array splice needs,
good luck

Comment: `Object.keys(i) == 'nean'` will never be true

Comment: Array [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) have only one required argument, start index.

Comment: @charlietfl why is that

Comment: @DylanMac Because Object.keys() returns an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for all your comments that helps a lot!

Comment: yes but providing one argument would result it in not doing anything which is redundant and not so smart ?! so in order to have a manipulation 2 arguments are needed correct?!

Comment: @Alisa-khodadadi it actually deletes everything before start index, might be useful in some situation (despite the fact that it mutates the array and should be banned :) )

Comment: sorry, it removes all items from given index (inclusive), not before